# Installing make with wget

Tags: centos, wget, make

How can I install `make` with `wget` on CentOS?

I tried:

```
cd /tmp wget ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.gz 
tar xfz make-3.81.tar.gz 
cd make-3.81 PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
./configure patch -p1<make-3.81-cygwin.patch patch -p0<make-3.81-cygwin_MAKE_expansion.patch PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
make PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
make install
```

However, I got an error message stating I had no acceptable C compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any specific problem with [yum](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/)?
Normally you would do `yum install make`
Or, maybe, `sudo yum install make`

---

Wow :-), Ok, i write the standard Make reference here, you take your pick on the source.

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.bz2
tar xfj make-3.81.tar.bz2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

---

And, while you are there, might want to [reinstall yum](http://sysadmingear.blogspot.com/2007/11/how-to-install-yum-on-centos.html) too...

---

Good to hear you have fixed it.

Comment: I accidentally removed yum.

Comment: Says I have no acceptable C compiler =(

Comment: configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: Ehh.... I found that my host has a recover option... so I did that and I have yum back and such.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: even if you uninstalled yum, you should still be able to use rpm directly, no?

Answer (score 2):

Just download rpm:

```
wget http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/centos/5.3/os/x86_64/CentOS/make-3.81-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

and install it via rpm:

```
rpm -ivh make-3.81-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
```